# How can I use the ICryptoTransform interface in a vb.net simple console app with a single module?

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple console app in vb.net, I want to keep it as simple as possible, right now I only have a module in the project (and I build from command line using vbc).

I'm trying to add a simple string encrypt/decrypt function for very light security usage.

I get the following error when I try to build it

```
accessory.vb(12) : error BC30375: 'New' cannot be used on an interface.

  dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = new ICryptoTransform()
```

See below the beginning of that module

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Module Accessory
    public function myEncrypt(plaintext as string)

      dim enc As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
      dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = new ICryptoTransform()
      dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = new ICryptoTransform()
      Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
      Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
```

Comment: First you have to decide on an encryption algorithm ([**`AES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx) is the most commonly used one), then you can call its [**`CreateEncryptor()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09d0kyb3(v=vs.110).aspx) and [**`CreateDecryptor()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79w421xb(v=vs.110).aspx) methods to create `ICryptoTransform`s. I recommend finding yourself a tutorial about it.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it with
    Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform
    encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KEY_128, IV_128)

Answer (score 0):

As per Visual Vincent's answer, the ICryptoTransform is not initialized with "= new ICryptoTransform()" but using the CreateEncryptor function of an encryption algorithm object such as the RijndaelManaged object

Full code follows, fixing the above problem of using the interface, however this code does not work fully. The decryption function will not return the same plaintext as that went into the encrypt function for as of yet unknown reasons.

Current console output :

```
MyConsoleApplication.exe
Encrypting plaintext 'SALUT'
Output is : D9ehMNg+i+5/ZFVakNwSyQ==
Decrypting cyphertext 'D9ehMNg+i+5/ZFVakNwSyQ=='
Output is : NU??
>??,♫?#?4?q?
```

Code :

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Module MyApplication
  Public Sub Main()
    Dim KEY_128 As Byte() = {42, 1, 52, 67, 231, 13, 94, 101, 123, 6, 0, 12, 32, 91, 4, 111, 31, 70, 21, 141, 123, 142, 234, 82, 95, 129, 187, 162, 12, 55, 98, 23}
    Dim IV_128 As Byte() = {234, 12, 52, 44, 214, 222, 200, 109, 2, 98, 45, 76, 88, 53, 23, 78}

    dim plaintext as string = "SALUT" 
    dim cyphertext as string, plaintext2 as string

    cyphertext = myEncrypt(plaintext,KEY_128 , IV_128)
    plaintext2 = myDecrypt(cyphertext,KEY_128 , IV_128)

    System.Console.Write("Encrypting plaintext '" & plaintext & "'" & vbcrlf & "Output is : " & cyphertext & vbcrlf)
    System.Console.Write("Decrypting cyphertext '" & cyphertext & "'" & vbcrlf & "Output is : " & plaintext2 & vbcrlf)

  End Sub

  public function myEncrypt(plaintext as string,KEY_128 As Byte(),IV_128 As Byte()) as string

    dim enc As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

    Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform
    encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KEY_128, IV_128)

    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    cryptoStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(plaintext), 0, plaintext.Length)
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()

  end function

  public function myDecrypt(cyphertext as string,KEY_128 As Byte(),IV_128 As Byte()) as string
    dim enc As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
    enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding

    Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform
    decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KEY_128, IV_128)

    Dim cypherTextBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cyphertext)
    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(cypherTextBytes)
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    Dim plainTextBytes(cypherTextBytes.Length) As Byte
    Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()
    return enc.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount)

  end function

End Module
```

Comment: There are a couple of things to take notice of... **First of all**, you have a typo in your `myDecrypt()` function: `decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KEY_128, IV_128)` - You were supposed to call _**`CreateDEcryptor()`**_. This is why it doesn't work; you're encrypting it again. || **Secondly**, there's no certainty that `enc.GetBytes()` will return the exact same number of bytes as `plaintext.Length`. Therefore you must place the result of `GetBytes()` in a byte array variable (`Byte()`) and then check _**its**_ length.

Comment: Finally, the `RijndaelManaged`, `MemoryStream` and `CryptoStream` all implement `IDisposable`. You're calling the `Close()` method in `myEncrypt`, but that part of the code will never execute because _**the function exits at `Return`**_. Instead you ought to wrap the three in [**`Using` blocks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) in both your functions (infact you should always use `Using` blocks when possible, rather than calling `Close()` or `Dispose()`).

Comment: Also, as a side note: Did you know that you can shorten all `Dim variable As Type = New Type()` to `Dim variable As New Type()`? For example, this: `Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()` can be shortened to this: `Dim symmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()`.

Comment: thank you for this wealth of knowledge, I will review all this when I get up tomorrow, thanks again